# Curves deformed by curve modifier have control points not placed correctly when in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I have a curve that is being used to deform another curve object that has different islands of curves. I can't figure out why in edit mode the control points of the deformed curve with islands of curves are not placed correctly. If I uncheck the "Display modifier in Edit mode" button on the curve modifier the deformed curves jump to the correct position of the control points. This action is the same as unchecking the "Display in viewport" button making it seem as if the "Display modifier in Edit mode" button isn't doing what it should be doing which is placing the control points where the deformed curves are. Both objects have the same location, rotation and scale. Is this a bug? Here is an image showing the problem. [image: curve-control-points-incorrect]

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for modifiers. Modifiers affect the location of vertices and handles **after** their original location is known in edit mode.

Take a cube with a sub-d modifier for example. In edit mode, with the On Cage and Edit Mode options clicked
[image]
selecting any of the vertices highlights the vertex in it's "On Cage" location, but the move gizmo is shown at it's original unmodified location
[image]

This is also true for curve objects, in edit mode their handles will be at their original, unmodified location.

A trick to overcome this, is to duplicate your original curve with the modifiers on it, then remove the modifiers from the duplicated curve, then link the curve data from the original curve. Once you've done this you can enter edit mode on the duplicated curve and see your handles in their "unmodified" locations. This way you can edit the duplicated curve and it will also change the original curve with the modifier so you'll be able to visualize both in real time.
The picture shows the duplicated curve in edit mode (the curve with the handles) and the original curve also in edit mode (because linked data objects always enter edit mode together) but with it's modifier intact
[image]

Comment: Hi @Psyonic, thank you for the help. I'm a little confused about how the "link the curve data to the original curve" should be used as a solution. Could you explain this a little more? First I need to duplicate the curve object that has the curve deform modifier. Then I delete the curve modifier from the duplicate and then?

Comment: Hey @LeoAguiar, I've updated my answer, hope it's clearer now 